# how to make this perl while loop faster

Tags: perl, while-loop

I did some timestamp prints from within script, this piece is taking too long: almost 5 minutes to complete...!!!

fyi, the strArr array contains about 1500 string elements. (this loop runs that many times)

the file tmp_FH_SR  is 27Mb and 300,000 lines of data.
the file tmp_FH_RL is 13 Mb with around 150,000 lines of data.

I have changed the names of variable to protect actual names...

in the first while loop, based on the fact that the $str was found only once in the file, i obtain another field from the matching record. I use this field to search for number of occurrences of this field in another file. Based on that output i add $str to an array.

```
my $tmp_srt;
foreach my $str (@strArr)
{
    my $tmp1;
    my $count=0;
    seek $tmp_FH_SR,0,0;
    while (<$tmp_FH_SR>)
    {
        my $line=$_;chomp($line);
        if ($line=~ m/\"$str\"/)
        {
            $count++;
            if ($count == 1)
            {
                my @tmp_line_ar = split(/\,/,$line);
                $tmp_str=$tmp_line_ar[10];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($count == 1)
    {
        my $k;
        seek $tmp_FH_RL,0,0;
        while (<$tmp_FH_RL>)
        {
            my $line=$_;chomp($line);
            if ($line=~m/\"$tmp_str\"/) {$k++;}
        }
        if($k == 1){push(@another_str_arr,$str);}
    }
}
```

how can i make it faster? read the 27mb and 13mb files in an array one time and work? I wanted to avoid that, as many other process be running on the host where this runs.

ty.

Comment: Please show the contents of the two data files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going at it backwards, which is one reason why it's taking so long.

`@strAtt` is only 1500 entries, and you're reading each file 1500 times because of your loop.

Put the entires in `@strArr` in a map or use a multi-dimentional array so you can keep track of your count for each entry. Read a line from the file, then loop over the 1500 entries. You now read in the file only once.